# php session between two pages

Tags: php, session

My goal is to open a new session (there is a login system with a session for the user ) when the user clicks play the `location_id`, then he is redirected to the next page and there he would select data from the db.
When `print_r` session I get empty session for `location_id` (user session is fine!)

here the user select a point

```
$location_id = $_GET['location_id'];

echo $location_id;


        var i ; var confirmed = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                map: map,
                icon :   locations[i][4] === '1' ?  red_icon  : purple_icon,
                html: "<div id='window_loc'>\n" +
                "<form method='POST' action='question.php'>\n" +
                "<table class=\"map1\">\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td><input type='hidden'  id='manual_description'/>"+locations[i][3]+"</td></tr>\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td><textarea disabled  id='question' placeholder='Question'>"+locations[i][5]+"</textarea></td></tr>\n" +
                "<tr>\n" +
                "<td><input type='hidden' name='location_id' id='location_id' value="+locations[i][0]+" /></td></tr>\n" +
                "<td><input id='button1' name='play' type='submit' value='play'/> </td></tr>\n" +
                "</table>\n" +
                "</form>\n" +
                "</div>"
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    confirmed =  locations[i][4] === '1' ?  'checked'  :  0;
                    $("#confirmed").prop(confirmed,locations[i][4]);
                    $("#location_id").val(locations[i][0]);
                    $("#description").val(locations[i][3]);
                    $("#form").show();
                    infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
        }
```

I've added this to the page where the user is redirected but the session is empty ( there is a session_start and it works - `print_r` shows user id)

```
$location_id = $_GET['location_id'];

echo $location_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help:

- you are using `$location_id = $_GET['location_id'];` (GET method), but in your JS you create a form with a `<form method='POST'` (POST method).

Isn't `$location_id` always empty because of this? Maybe that's why nothing changes in your `$_SESSION`.

Where are you updating your `$_SESSION` data? (it is not shown in the code).
Can you change it to: `$_POST['location_id']` and retry?

Comment: i have changed the action to get and had secsess tnx!!